# want to build something similar cylindo or Adobe scene7

Tags: visualizer

I want to develop something like http://www.cylindo.com/solution/ (360 HD Viewer) or adobe scene7 where the user can change the colors or patterns of our products on fly by selecting the choices, something like visualizer.

So, I want to understand the technologies that can be used to develop this and some examples would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Any help here please?

Comment: I'm looking to build something similar to Cylindo Viewer for my room scene viewer.